# Get overridden file data?

Tags: sql, backup, windows-xp, data-recovery, file-recovery

I have a script file. Unfortunately I've overridden it with some other data. I need the old data. <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is not working.

How do I recover it?

Comment: I guess you data are lost. but give more details, what's your os ? what does your script do ? ...

Comment: I'm using windows XP.. Script is SQL script...

Comment: be more precise and explain what you're trying to do. I guess you're trying to modify a SQL database !?

Comment: Yesterday i generated script. Today unfortunately i saved some other script data with the same file name.So i lost my older script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately some editors are not supporting of crtl + Z so only not able to recover the data..

Answer (score -1):

are you using file versioning? what OS, what version?

What is the File structure? NTFS?

if you overwrite a file in NTFS it tends to delete the first file and put in the second, not systematically destroy the file (so you can recover the file with an undelete utility.

first, rename the current file, then open an undelete utility (you don't want to download anything to this computer as you may overwrite the file.)
run it from a memory stick.

the safest thing to do if it's critical is to image the device off to a donor scratch media and work from there.